# WifiWizard 2 ERROR_ADDING_NETWORK

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-native

I need some help. I try to develop an app which is setting up the wifi connection on an android device.
I try to use WifiWizard2 with `this.wifiWizard2.connect(ssid, bindAll, password, algorithm, isHiddenSSID)` but when i try the app on an Device (Android 12) i only get the Error: `ERROR_ADDING_NETWORK`.

Here is the code I use, i hope you can help me:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


declare var WifiWizard2: any;


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
  
})
export class HomePage {
  ssid = "ubntPOS";
  password = "6545A-UAPACL";
  info_txt = "";

  async getNetworks() {
    this.info_txt = "test123";
    try {
      await WifiWizard2.timeout(4000);
      await WifiWizard2.connect(this.ssid,true,this.password,'WEP',false);
      this.info_txt = "";
    } catch (error) {
      this.info_txt = error;
    }
  }
}
```

For example:

```
WifiWizard2.scan();
```

does work properly and list all networks nearby.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution-

When I degraded my targetSdkVersion the everything is working fine.
The targetSdkVersion or api-level < = 29.